# Union all type query with python pandas

Tags: python, union, pandas

I am attempting to use pandas to perform data analysis on a flat source of data. Specifically, what I'm attempting to accomplish is the equivalent of a Union All query in SQL.

I am using the read_csv() method to input the data and the output has unique integer indices and approximately 30+ columns.

Of these columns, several contain identifying information, whilst others contain data.

In total, the first 6 columns contain identifying informations which uniquely identifies an entry. Following these 6 columns there are a range of columns (A,B... etc) which reference the value. Some of these columns are linked together in sets, for example (A,B,C) belong together, as do (D,E,F).

However, (D,E,F) are also related to (A,B,C) as follows ((A,D),(B,E),(C,F)).
What I am attempting to do is take my data set which has as follows:

```
(id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,id6,A,B,C,D,E,F)
```

and return the following

```
((id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,id6,A,B,C),
 (id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,id6,D,E,F))
```

Here, as A and D are linked they are contained within the same column.

(Note, this is a simplification, there are approximately 12 million unique combinations in the total dataset)

I have been attempting to use the merge, concat and join functions to no avail. I feel like I am missing something crucial as in an SQL database I can simply perform a union all query (which is quite slow admittedly) to solve this issue.

I have no working sample code at this stage.

Another way of writing this problem based upon some of the pandas docs.

```
left = key lval
right = key rval
merge(left, right, on=key) = key, lval, rval
```

Instead I want:

```
left = kev, lval
right = key, lval
union(left, right) = key, lval
                     key, rval
```

I'm not sure if a new indexing key value would need to be created for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to accomplish what I initially asked for.
It did require a bit of massaging of column names however.

Solution (using pseudo code):

Set up dataframes with the relevant data. e.g.

```
left = (id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,id6,A,B,C)
right = (id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,id6,D,E,F)
middle = (id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,id6,G,H,I)
```

Note, here, that for me dataset this resulted in my having non-unique indexing keys for each of the ids. That is, a key is present for each row in left and right.

Rename the column names.

```
col_names = [id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,id6,val1,val2,val3]
left.columns = col_names
right.columns = col_names
middle.columns = col_names
```

Concatenate these

```
pieces = [left, right, middle]
new_df = concat(pieces)
```

Now, this will create a new dataframe which contains x unique indexing values and 3x entries. This isn't quite ideal but it will do for now, the major shortfall of this is that you cannot uniquely access a single entry row anymore, they will come in triples. To access the data you can create a new dataframe based on the unique id values.

e.g.

```
check_df = new_df[(new_df[id1] == 'id1') & (new_df[id2] == 'id2') ... etc])
print check_df

key, id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6, A, B, C
key, id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6, D, E, F
key, id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6, G, H, I
```

Now, this isn't quite ideal but it's the format I needed for some of my other analysis. It may not be applicable for all parties.

If anyone has a better solution please do share it, I'm relatively new to using pandas with python.

Comment: You can use the keys argument for concat, this will result in a MultiIndex and will allow you to uniquely select data: concat(pieces, keys=['left', 'middle', 'right']. I would also set (id1, ..., id6) as index, this will make it less verbose to select data.